# selection of DateTime.Now in Web Service

Tags: c#, web-services, datetime

I have a web service and I'm trying to have the following.

I'd like to get in ProcessReqDate column DateTime.Now (like 2016-11-16 14:32:37.733) but instead I get this (2016-11-17 00:00:00.000).

```
if (!DateTime.TryParseExact(OrderReq.RequestedProcessDate, "yyyy-MM-dd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out dateField) ||
    dateField < DateTime.Today ||
    order.PODate > dateField)
{
    orderInfo.status = "Fail";
    orderInfo.order_number = orderNo;
    orderInfo.notes = "Invalid Request Delivery Date: " + OrderReq.RequestedProcessDate + " (yyyy-MM-dd)" + Environment.NewLine;
    orderFailed = true;
}
else
{
    order.ProcessDate = DateTime.Today;
}

if (order.ProcessDate == DateTime.Today)
{
    order.ProcessReqDate = DateTime.Now;
}
else
{
    order.ProcessReqDate = DateTime.Today;
}
```

Comment: Are you using DateTime everywhere ? or some other datatype?

Comment: whats your question? Why are u using DateTime.Today, If you want to set DaTime.Now?

Comment: Then explain you question properly, its not clear by your code

Comment: I 'm looking for a selection like:
 if ProcessReqDate is DateTime.Now
   then 
    ProcessDate = DateTime.Now (date+time)
   else
    ProcessDate = DateTime.Today (just date + time at 00:00:00)

Comment: what is this ? DateTime.Now (date+time)

Comment: This ..you are already doing in your code. then why u doing this?
if (order.ProcessDate == DateTime.Today)
{
    order.ProcessReqDate = DateTime.Now;
}
else
{
    order.ProcessReqDate = DateTime.Today;
}

Comment: the display of date and time...                                                                          DateTime.Now shows the time like 2016-11-16 14:32:37.733,                         DateTime.Today shows like 2016-11-16 00:00:00.000                                        I want it like in .Now and I get it like in .Today.....  :(

Comment: What u said , is not matching with your condition...just check it

Comment: that's why I'm posting... what am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

If you rewrite the code a bit then you can make it clearer what is meant to be happening. It *appears* that you want to set `order.ProcessReqDate` to `DateTime.Now` if there is no problem and set it to `DateTime.Today` if there was a problem.

You can also usefully give a reason for the failure so that it is easier for the user to understand what went wrong.

I have no idea of the context of the code you showed, so I just put it into a `void`.

```
using System;
using System.Globalization;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        public enum OrderInfoStatus
        {
            Failure = 0,
            Success = 1
        }

        class OrderReq
        {
            public string RequestedProcessDate { get; set; }
        }

        class OrderInfo
        {
            public OrderInfoStatus Status { get; set; }
            public string OrderNumber { get; set; }
            public string Notes { get; set; }
        }

        class Order
        {
            public DateTime ProcessDate { get; set; }
            public DateTime ProcessReqDate { get; set; }
            public DateTime PODate { get; set; }
        }

        void X(OrderReq orderReq, Order order, OrderInfo orderInfo, string orderNo)
        {
            DateTime dateField;
            bool isValidRequestedProcessDate = DateTime.TryParseExact(orderReq.RequestedProcessDate, "yyyy-MM-dd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out dateField);

            bool isGoodDate = true;
            string problemArea = string.Empty;

            if (!isValidRequestedProcessDate)
            {
                isGoodDate = false;
                problemArea = "Could not parse requested process date.";
            }
            else if (dateField < DateTime.Today)
            {
                isGoodDate = false;
                problemArea = "Requested process date is before today.";
            }
            else if (dateField > order.PODate)
            {
                isGoodDate = false;
                problemArea = "Requested process date is after PO date.";
            }

            if (isGoodDate)
            {
                orderInfo.Status = OrderInfoStatus.Success;
                orderInfo.OrderNumber = orderNo;
                order.ProcessDate = DateTime.Now;
            }
            else
            {
                orderInfo.Status = OrderInfoStatus.Failure;
                orderInfo.OrderNumber = orderNo;
                orderInfo.Notes = "Invalid Request Delivery Date: " +
                    orderReq.RequestedProcessDate +
                    " (yyyy-MM-dd) - " +
                    problemArea +
                    Environment.NewLine;
                order.ProcessReqDate = DateTime.Today;
                //orderFailed = true; /* use orderInfo.Status for this instead */
            }

        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
        }
    }
}
```

It would also be a good idea to use UTC datetimes (e.g. `DateTime.UtcNow.Date`) instead of local datetimes. You can always convert a UTC datetime to the local datetime, but if the locale is unknown then it is impossible to do the reverse.